# Entity Framework (CRUD with Knockout and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, wcf, knockout.js

I was able to get the first attempt to create the knockout restful service, but when implementing it in Angular, the database showed an ID with every other field labeled undefined. I attempted to recreate the WCF Service and put in the information corresponding to the SQL DB linked with the Visual Studio Project. After attempting this, I am not getting this error that also prevents the data from being stored. Clicked on the exception help link and was left on a page that had a sentence of advice for a issue that wasn't that error. I'd post a picture but I don't have enough rep on this site to do so.

**Here's the exception**

```
TypeInitializationException was unhandled by user code    
An exception of type 'System.TypeIntifializationException' occured in 
EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: 
The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.AppConfig' threw an exception.
```

And also both of the needed references were added into the project through the packages. Any advice would help, already created this project multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

This typically means the app.config being used by your solution (generally whichever one is the startup project) doesn't contain EF's initialization information and/or the connection string for the EF context. Either install EF in that project or copy the relevant lines from another config.